# C# Linq query for matching lists exactly

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of IDs and collection of objects, each with its own child list of IDs.  I want a linq query that will return any of the objects for which its child list exactly matches the list of IDs.  Here is what I have, and I think it works -- but it's ugly, and requires two steps.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
var inputIDs = new List<int> {1, 5, 8, 10, 12};
var object1 = new {name = "object1", IDs = new List<int> {9, 10, 11, 12}};
var object2 = new {name = "object2", IDs = new List<int> {1, 5, 8, 12}};
var object3 = new {name = "object3", IDs = new List<int> {1, 5, 8, 10, 12}};

var objects = new List<object> {object1, object2, object3};

var candidateObjects = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.All(i => inputIDs.Contains(i)));
var exactMatches = candidateObjects.Where(o => inputIDs.All(i => o.IDs.Contains(i)));

// exactMatches should only contain object3
```

Comment: will u accept a solution outside linq ?

Comment: Can your list of child IDs contain duplicate IDs, something like `new {name = "object3", IDs = new List<int> {1, 1, 5, 8, 10}};`?

Comment: You know that you can chain those two steps?

Comment: can u show an example like given list and expected list ?

Comment: This will require two checks.  Your first linq.where identifies an object with all of the input ids.  You would need to do a second check of some sort to determine if the object has any additional ids.  For example your second linq.where, this could be simplified if neither the object nor the input list will have duplicates.  If no dupes, your second check could simply compare counts.  The important note is that it will require you to do two checks.

Comment: @zackraiyan sure :)

Comment: @elgonzo no there will be no dupes in either list

Comment: If your exact match definition is all value exist in both of list (duplication not important) you can change and found it exat match list in one step.

`var exactMatches = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.All(i => inputIDs.Contains(i)) && inputIDs.Distinct().Count() == o.IDs.Distinct().Count());`
<= this use line rather than use this =>
`var candidateObjects = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.All(i => inputIDs.Contains(i)));`

Comment: @Fabio yes I know the two steps can be chained but it doesn't really make the solution any prettier.  I was hoping for a more succinct syntax like a join or intersect.

Comment: The `.SequenceEqual` will return true for two lists that contain the exact same elements in the same order. Is that what you want? You don't show any examples of objects that have all the `inputIDs` but in a different order, or have all of them plus other, different numbers, or that have all of them plus one or more repeated numbers. It would be nice if you added these inputs `{ 1, 8, 5, 12, 10 }, {1, 5, 8, 8, 10, 12}, {1, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`:

```
var inputIDs = new List<int> { 1, 5, 8, 10, 12 };
var object1 = new { name = "object1", IDs = new List<int> { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };
var object2 = new { name = "object2", IDs = new List<int> { 1, 5, 8, 12 } };
var object3 = new { name = "object3", IDs = new List<int> { 1, 5, 8, 10, 12 } };

var objects = new[] { object1, object2, object3 }.ToList();

var exactMatches = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.SequenceEqual(inputIDs));
```

Per @AnupSharma, you will need to sort if your sequences could be out of order (and now performance rears its head):

```
var inputIDs = new[] { 1, 5, 8, 10, 12 }.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();

//...

var exactMatches = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(inputIDs));
```

A (slight) performance improvement can be had by testing for `Count` since we know the sources are `List`s:

```
var exactMatches = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.Count == inputIDs.Count && o.IDs.OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(inputIDs));
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about!  Thank you

Comment: This will not work if the sequence is not in same order.

Comment: I can ensure they are in the same order.  Sorry, should have included that in the question.

Comment: @AnupSharma At that point `Except`/`Count` might be just as performant.

Comment: @NetMage Except/Count should be a bit faster than OrderBy/SequenceEqual. Except is O(2n) (in the case), Count is O(1), OrderBy is O(n.logn).

Comment: @MBakardzhiev I assume that is for `List` (and `SequenceEqual` would be O(n)?). Perhaps a `Count` comparison before the `SequenceEqual` would help if performance mattered.

Comment: @NetMage Don't know about SequenceEqual, but I guess it first compares length and then compares values one by one in one for loop, so probably yes, it is O(n). Count is O(1) for ICollection implementations. Except compares in two foreach loops, while OrderBy performs a quicksort.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev From the [C# Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/), `SequenceEqual` doesn't special case `ICollection` and test for `Count`, just steps through the two iterators. So testing for `Count` would be helpful since we know they are `List`s.

Comment: @NetMage So it is O(2n) on equal collections.

Answer (score 2):

A similar but faster solution would be using `Except` with a count check:

```
objects.Where(o => !o.IDs.Except(inputIDs).Any() && o.IDs.Count == inputIDs.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a check for count of elements will be enough for your example

```
var result = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.Count == inputIDs.Count)
                    .Where(o => o.IDs.All(id => inputIDs.Contains(id)));
```

You can do some optiomization by using `HashSet`

```
var inputs =new HashSet<int>(inputsIDs);
var result = objects.Where(o => o.IDs.Count == inputIDs.Count)
                    .Where(o => o.IDs.All(id => inputs.Contains(id)));
```